# Excluding lines that contain a pattern before replacing in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, ack

I have the following code to replace version string from a set of files

```
ack --ignore-file=is:HISTORY.md -l --print0 '1\.1\.1' | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's/1\.1\.1/1\.1\.2/g'
```

Now, I realized there are some lines in the doxygen comment that also have the version string like this.

```
/**
 * Generate Tag id from Tag name
 *
 * @since 1.1.1
 * @static
 * @access public
 *
 */
```

How can I modify the above snippet so that lines that contain `@since` will be excluded?

Comment: I do hope that `\2` is a typo, because otherwise it is a silent error in your code. `\2` is a backreference to a capture group, which you are not using, so `\2` is interpolated into the empty string, and because you are not using warnings, you get no warning about it.

Comment: @TLP Yes was a typo. I just fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Lines that contain `1.1.1` are version lines?

Comment: @sin Yes. And in this case `1.1.1` is the current version number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To exclude lines with `@since` you could try this instead of your current perl replace code:

```
!/\@since/ && s/1\.1\.1/1.1.2/g
```

or even

```
/\@since/ || s/1\.1\.1/1.1.2/g
```

Comment: Thanks this works. BTW, don't we have to escapes `.` in the replacement string?

Comment: @Sudar - No--they're not matching.

Comment: @Sudar, regex pattern meta characters are not valid in the replacement and thus don't need to be escaped.